# UIPopOverController issues while autorotation

Tags: uipopovercontroller

I am presenting a UIPopovercontroller using PresentPopOverFromRect: method. in Portrait Orientation. When i autorotate to Landscape UIPopoverController is not presenting at the proper position. How to position the UIPopoverController while autorotating the device.

Comment: Show the code where you call presentPopoverFromRect.  Do all the view controllers return YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this function:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

where you can change the dimension and position of the UIPopovercontroller depending of your current orientation. This function is convenient because it is called just before the screen is being redrawn and just before the user interface begins to rotate.

You should check this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPad_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling_%28Xcode_4%29) for an understanding of how you should handle the layout for different orientations of the IPad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as [tiguero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997084/tiguero) says, in your custom UIViewController, you can override the method:

```c
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [self.popOverViewController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    CGRect yourNewRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20, 20);
    [self.popOverViewController presentPopoverFromRect:yourNewRect inView:yourView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

You can have a try!