# UIPopoverController. Device does not autorotate (iPad)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

When i have have this line of code in my app, iPad (device and simulator) does not autorotate:

```
popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
```

When i comment that line out, it autorotates.

Also, i'm presenting it this way:

```
[popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:addButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Does your app support landscape and portrait?

Comment: @JasperPol Yes. All the orientations are enabled. Overrided the shouldAutrotate methods too.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512782/uipopovercontroller-issues-while-autorotation

Comment: @JasperPol That problem seems to be incorrect positioning pf the popover after rotating. For me, rotation/orientation change does not register at all. I also tried the those suggestions but am still unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...
I was using the main/parent view controller of the popOverviewController, in its `initWithContentViewController:` method/initializer. (meant to use an UIImagePickerController instance).